# PHP code for encryption and decryption that creates different cipher text on each execution. Can anybody help me with an equivalent code in PL/SQL

Tags: php, plsql, oracle11g

```
$data = 'Durgadevi'.date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$b = encrypt($data);
echo '<b>actual data: </b>'.$data.'<br><b> encrypted code: </b>'.$b;
function encrypt($string)
{
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = '123456';
    $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';
    $key = hash('sha256',$secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256',$secret_iv),0,16);
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string,$encrypt_method,$key,0,$iv);
    return $output;
}
```

*After executing encrypt function*

> OUTPUT:
>
> actual data: Durgadevi11:07:40
>
> encrypted code: Fxf6Q73Fs5byu6e2R0nTwG01n4vsoBAyfefSY5HBSWM=

```
$data = 'Fxf6Q73Fs5byu6e2R0nTwG01n4vsoBAyfefSY5HBSWM=';
$b = decrypt($data);
echo '<b> actual data: </b>'.$data.'<br><b> decrypted code: </b>'.$b;

function decrypt($string)
{
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = '123456';
    $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';
    $key = hash('sha256',$secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256',$secret_iv),0,16);
    $output = openssl_decrypt($string,$encrypt_method,$key,0,$iv);
    return $output;
}
```

*After executing decrypt function*

> OUTPUT:
>
> actual data: Fxf6Q73Fs5byu6e2R0nTwG01n4vsoBAyfefSY5HBSWM=
>
> decrypted code: Durgadevi11:07:40

Comment: you can use `dbms_crypto` [here is a documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_crypto.htm#i1004145)

Comment: ya i tried using it with salt as date and time.but length of the cipher text is not differing much. So i need some other encryption algos that is supported by oracle

Comment: then you should rephrase your question and describe in more detail. What did you try, what was the result, what is the expected result. wi can not help you if you do not ask concrete questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below function for encryption and decryption.

```
function encryptDecrypt($action, $data) {
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key ="g3hR0m9FY1r+9ZXLdriXI4U6AxsYqlbISe8Qne9DuJU9R1AlvsV1GWQMQhP0NcvvtnvSB1AoIBAQD8zQp+VhgSH";
    $secret_iv = "xaghJBqlqQPkox2djChy3+3tmEPZJpypp4Euy2sDLSgyP+nsecrkP18bfl2i+ChPAoIBAQC3FijLZr74H0m9oGj0hPAlfcAh5bTMvAF4993M8BjncApCzKMOK3CLT+278dquihNCyrbK6/FjDMw9sGl5kctenaOVcvtdupMWtX9U9KmH8G1XCX/Xr/umpgAxjh+l69v4lrDRln48/gT9zfdKjZ5OiuW+M+gbNL6qGAM";

    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

    if ($action == 'encrypt') {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($data, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
    } else if ($action == 'decrypt') {
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }
    return $output;
}

//Call as below

$string = 'Durgadevi'.date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
echo $encString = encryptDecrypt('encrypt', $string);
echo "<br/>";
echo encryptDecrypt('decrypt', $encString);
```